# Изображения на php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на php написать код, чтобы при нажатии на изображение, оно открывалось в новом окне?

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос не про php, а про HTML, наверное? `target="_blank"` в ссылке откроет ее в новом окне/табе. Примерно так:

```
<a href="http://вашсайт.ru/большаякартинка" target="_blank">
    <img src="адрес кликабельной картинки" />
</a>
```

Comment: спасибо, как в html я знаю)

Comment: Если бы озадачились сформулировать вопрос более грамотно, нашли бы уже в процессе, ответ.
Например, не в новом окне, а "поверх", "во всплывающем", узнали бы, что это на английском называется Lightbox, и есть куча готовых решений. Не на php, на JS.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a target="_blank" href="orig.jpg"> 
    <img  src="min_copy.jpg">
</a>
```

Вам не надо php, создаете обычную ссылку с настройкой (target="_blank"), что бы открыть в новом окне.

Comment: спасибо за помощь)))

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас принять показывать изображения в popup-окне или с показом / скрытием тега `<DIV>` (вариантов реализации много). Вот простой пример на JS это, примерно, выглядит так:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
 function openPopupWin()
 {
 var sURL, sDesrc;
 var sParams = new Array(6);

 // загружаемый URL в новом окне
 sURL = "1.png";
 // настройки открываемого окна браузера
 sParams[0] = "500"; // ширина окна в пикселях
 sParams[1] = "160"; // высота окна в пикселях
 // "no" - скрыть элемент, "yes" - показать
 sParams[2] = "no"; // наличие статус строки
 sParams[3] = "no"; // наличие кнопок (toolbar)
 sParams[4] = "no"; // наличие меню
 sParams[5] = "no"; // наличие скроллингов
 sDesrc = "width=" + sParams[0] + ", height=" + sParams[1] +
 ", status=" + sParams[2] + ", toolbar=" + sParams[3] +
 ", menubar=" + sParams[4] + ", scrollbars=" + sParams[5];
 window.open(sURL, "displayWindow", sDesrc);
 }
 </script>
<a href="javascript: openPopupWin()" title="My image"> <img src="1.png"/></a>
</html>
```

Вставляйте данный код в Ваш php-файл - все будет работать. Но если действительно Вам требуется открытие в новом окне (вкладке) - то предыдущие ответы абсолютно правильны, они являются "классикой" HTML.

Comment: благодарю)